# How to reference a DUT from another PLC project

Tags: plc, twincat

I have created 2 PLC projects. On for the main logic, and the other for visualizations.

Data will be transferred between both projects using input/output. I want to create a motor HMI and have grouped the motor controls in a DUT in the main PLC project.

How can I now reference this DUT in the visualization project?

Answer (score 3):

Just found out the answer myself.

**External types**

A DUT can be referenced from another project if it as an external type.
Local DUT's can easily be made external:

1. Right click on the DUT
2. Press 'Convert to Global Data Type'
3. The DUT will be moved from DUT-folder to External Types folder, and necessary attributes are automatically added.

See this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBTXG.png).

Comment: It's not an answer.It's a comment!

Comment: It seems to be a valid solution to the original question; why do you think it should be a comment?

Comment: Just try not to edit the structure much, there are many things you need to keep in mind (mostly references), since every change in the data type will create a new GUID for that new edited type. Same data types (names) might pile up due to references to them, mostly because the PLC and other TwinCAT (sutch as IO links) do not get updated data type. I had quite a lot of problems sharing data types betwen 3 PLCs. Best practice is to be sure you no longer have to edit that data type, because as mentioned, editing brings a lot of unwanted pain :) .